# /base_scan observation buffer has not been updated

Tags: navigation, global-costmap, hokuyo, local-costmap, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i am trying to get the navigation stack running. Hokuyo is the laser scanner i am using. When i am launching move_base_local.launch i receive the warning

"The /base_scan observation buffer has not been updated for XX.XX seconds, and it should be updated every 0.20 seconds."

My launch file is:

-->

```
<param name="T" type="double" value="0.2"/>
<param name="dt" type="double" value="0.1"/>

<node pkg="youbot_navigation_common" type="lowpass_filter" respawn="false" name="lowpass_filter" output="screen">
    
</node>

<!-- for moving -->
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base_node" output="screen">
    <!-- Load common configuration files -->
<remap from="cmd_vel" to="move_base/cmd_vel"/> 
    <rosparam file="$(find youbot_navigation_common)/config/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find youbot_navigation_common)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find youbot_navigation_common)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <!--<rosparam file="$(find youbot_navigation)/navigation_common/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" ns="TrajectoryPlannerROS" />-->

    <!-- Load global navigation specific parameters -->
    <!--<rosparam file="$(find youbot_navigation)/navigation_local/config/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />-->
    <rosparam file="$(find youbot_navigation_local)/config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find youbot_navigation_local)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find youbot_navigation_common)/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
</node>
```

My local_costmap_params.yaml is:

```
local_costmap:
publish_voxel_map: true
global_frame: odom
robot_base_frame: base_footprint
update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 2.0
static_map: false
rolling_window: true
width: 10.0
height: 10.0
resolution: 0.05
origin_x: 0.0
origin_y: 0.0
```

My global_costmap is:

```
global_costmap:
publish_voxel_map: true
global_frame: odom
robot_base_frame: base_footprint
update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 2.0
static_map: false
rolling_window: true
width: 20.0
height: 20.0
resolution: 0.05
origin_x: 0.0
origin_y: 0.0
```

My costmap_common_params.yaml is this:

```
map_type: costmap
transform_tolerance: 0.2
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
inflation_radius: 0.25

observation_sources: base_scan

#base_scan_marking: {sensor_frame: base_scan_link,
#                    data_type: PointCloud2,
#                    topic: /base_scan/marking,
#                    expected_update_rate: 0.2,
#                    observation_persistence: 0.0,
#                    marking: true,
#                    clearing: false,
#                    min_obstacle_height: 0.06,
#                    max_obstacle_height: 2.0}

base_scan: {sensor_frame: base_laser_front_link,
        data_type: LaserScan,
        topic: /base_scan,
        expected_update_rate: 0.2,
        observation_persistence: 0.0,
        marking: true,
        clearing: true,
        min_obstacle_height: -0.10,
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0}
```

What am i missing or doing wrong? Cannot figure it out myself and couldn't find any proper answers online.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172051//base_scan-observation-buffer-has-not-been-updated/) by [m.hoev](https://answers.ros.org/users/16886/m.hoev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-05-30**:
Does the message appear once or many times? Can you confirm that the topic is properly connected while running?

**Comment by [m.hoev](https://answers.ros.org/users/16886/m.hoev/) on 2014-06-11**:
Sorry for answering that late. The message appears again and again. What do you mean with "the topic is properly connected?"
I am using ros hydro on ubuntu 12.04 by the way. Just in case this is important.

Note that i added my costmap_common_params.yaml.

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2014-06-11**:
check if Hokuyo publishes under /base_scan, according to http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node#Published_Topics it publishes under /scan by default

**Comment by [m.hoev](https://answers.ros.org/users/16886/m.hoev/) on 2014-06-11**:
No, it is publishing under /scan.

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2014-06-11**:
then you have to change the topic in your costmap_common_params.yaml to /scan, you currently have set it to /base_scan.
Does it works then ?

**Comment by [m.hoev](https://answers.ros.org/users/16886/m.hoev/) on 2014-06-13**:
No. It still doesn't work. I changed sensor frame to laser aswell, because i need to chose laser in rviz to see laser scans but this did not solve the problem either. Thougt the issue could be with my tf tree, but it is odom -> base_footprint -> laser...this should be correct too.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-13**:
Can you post the updated configuration that you're now using, as well as the result of running rostopic info /scan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My updated costmap_common_params.yaml is:

```
map_type: costmap transform_tolerance:
0.2 obstacle_range: 2.5 raytrace_range: 3.0 inflation_radius:
0.25

observation_sources: base_scan

#base_scan_marking: {sensor_frame: base_scan_link,
#                    data_type: PointCloud2,
#                    topic: /base_scan/marking,
#                    expected_update_rate: 0.2,
#                    observation_persistence: 0.0,
#                    marking: true,
#                    clearing: false,
#                    min_obstacle_height: 0.06,
#                    max_obstacle_height: 2.0}

base_scan: {sensor_frame: laser,
            data_type: LaserScan,
            topic: /scan,
            expected_update_rate: 0.2,
            observation_persistence: 0.0,
            marking: true,
            clearing: true,
            min_obstacle_height: -0.10,
            max_obstacle_height: 2.0}
```

I think it is running properly now. The result of rostopic info /scan is:

```
Type: sensor_msgs/LaserScan
Publishers:   * /hokuyo_node (http://J-youBot:XXXXX/)
Subscribers:   * /move_base_node (http://J-youBot:XXXXX/)
```

The warning stops after receiving info: odom received

---

Originally posted by [m.hoev](https://answers.ros.org/users/16886/m.hoev/) with karma: 68 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-17**:
Running properly now --> No more help needed?

**Comment by [m.hoev](https://answers.ros.org/users/16886/m.hoev/) on 2014-06-17**:
yes, thanks a lot